# How can I use Java Native Interface to pass a byte array into a C function which takes a char* as an argument?

Tags: java, c, char, java-native-interface, buffer

So I need to use JNI to call a C function from java. I've been able to successfully do this when passing in different data types (create the native variables, header file, shared library, blah blah), but can't get it to work with a byte array. Here's my C function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void encrypt(int size, unsigned char *buffer);
void decrypt(int size, unsigned char *buffer);

void encrypt(int size, unsigned char *buffer){
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        unsigned char c = buffer[i];
        printf("%c",c);
    }
}
void decrypt(int size, unsigned char *buffer){
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        unsigned char c = buffer[i];
        printf("%c",c);
    }
}
```

And here's my java code (I understand that after making a header file from this, I have to replace the C function declarations by the JNI code in the header file)

```
class Tester{
    public native void encrypt(int size, char *buffer);
    public native void decrypt(int size, char *buffer);
    static{
    System.loadLibrary("buffer");
    {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Tester test = new Tester();
        String hello = "hello";
        byte[] byteHello = hello.getBytes();
        test.encrypt(5,byteHello);
        test.decrypt(5,byteHello);
    }
}
```

I get that the char* type isn't supported in Java and that's why I'm getting an error trying to compile. Perhaps I should change the type to char[] in Java? Anyways, my goal is to be able to pass a byte array in Java into my C function, iterate through the byte array, and print out each element.

Comment: The java ```char``` and C ```char``` types are incompatible, it would probably be better to pass the ```byte[]``` to C and then convert each element on demand

Comment: "How can I use Java Native Interface to pass a byte array into a C function which takes a char* as an argument?" - you can't, but you can pass a byte array into a C function which takes a Java byte array as an argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java `char` and C `char` types are incompatible, it would probably be better to pass the `byte[]` to C and then convert each element on demand.

---

Something along these lines:

Main.java:

```
//...Code to load library...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    passBytes("hello".getBytes());
}

public static native void passBytes(byte[] bytes);
```

Main.c:

```
#include "Main.h" // Main.h is generated

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_passBytes
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jbyteArray array) {
    unsigned char* buffer = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
    jsize size = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%c", buffer[i]);
    }

    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, array, buffer, JNI_ABORT);
 }
```

---

`jbyteArray` is nothing more then a stub type, defined in `jni.h`:

```
struct _jobject;
typedef struct _jobject *jobject;
typedef jobject jarray;
typedef jarray jbyteArray;
```

It doesn't actually contain any data. It is more or less just a memory adress.

To get the elements from it we pass it to [`GetByteArrayElements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17382) (since the type was `byte[]`) which can than ask the VM to retrieve the elements in a C style array. (It might or might not make a copy. See doc)

The same is done for the array length.

To tell the VM we're done with the array. We call [`ReleaseArrayElements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17440).

Also, `jbyte` is defined as `signed char`, so just using the result of `GetByteArrayElements` as an `unsigend char*` instead of `jbyte*` is safe in this case.

Comment: A bit more explanation would make this a better answer.  A copy from your comment would be a good start, but it would also be worth mentioning that a Java array as received by a native method is *not* a C array.  You have to use the appropriate JNI function to obtain from it an actual C array (as you demonstrate), and that puts some additional requirements on the overall native method implementation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the suggestion. I kind of assumed that OP already knew most of this. But any ways, I sometimes forget other people will read this too ;)

Comment: The importance of the Release* functions is to unpin the objects in the JVM heap. The array elements are not necessarily copied by Get* and so JNI_ABORT does not necessarily avoid modifying the JVM array; It only saves time _if_ there was a copy..

Comment: @JornVernee Hey, thanks a lot! This works, and I am effectively able to print and change the values inside the memory buffer. Is there any chance you could answer my very similar question regarding calling a C library from python? You seem to know what you're talking about. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mr.Pickles No sorry, I don't know much about python.

Comment: @JornVernee So when I modify the loop in the C method to say buffer[i] = buffer[i] + 1, and run the java program, I can see that it prints "ifmmp" instead of "hello", which is what I want. Is there any way to see that change from the java side? Is there any way for me to say: 'String hello = "hello"' and when I call the method: 'passBytes(hello.getBytes)' it actually updates the value of the string in JAVA to "ifmmp"? So that if I print hello, I would get the value that the C method incremented that was stored in the heap? Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Pickles Not directly, since strings in java are immutable, the byte array returned by ```String::getBytes``` is an encoding of the actual value in the platform's standard character set. By passing ```0``` instead of ```JNI_ABORT``` to the release function, it will copy back any changes. You can then use the changed ```byte[]``` in java to create a new string. i.e. ```byte[] b = "hello".getBytes(); passBytes(b); String str = new String(b);```.

Comment: @JornVernee I changed it to 0, but in the case when I call passBytes(b), make the string str and print it in java, I still see "hello" and not "ifmmp". I want it so that if I take a byte array in java and pass it through the C function then print out the same byte array, the incremented value in the function changes the value when printed to java. Is that possible?

Comment: @Mr.Pickles I tested it out and it works fine for me, with the exact code I posted in the last comment. I don't know what to tell you...

Comment: @JornVernee You're saying that when you call passBytes(b), then print out str, your output is ifmmpifmmp?

Comment: @JohnVernee Nevermind, got it to work. Thanks for the help!!